# Cannot get querySelectorAll to work with puppeteer (returns undefined)

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, queryselector

I'm trying to practice some web scraping with prices from a supermarket. It's with node.js and puppeteer. I can navigate throught the website in beginning with accepting cookies and clicking a "load more button". But then when I try to read div's containing the products with querySelectorAll I get stuck. It returns undefined even though I wait for a specific div to be present. What am I missing?

Problem is at the end of the code block.

```
const { product } = require("puppeteer");

const scraperObjectAll = {
    url: 'https://www.bilkatogo.dk/s/?query=',
    async scraper(browser) {
        let page = await browser.newPage();
        console.log(`Navigating to ${this.url}`);
        await page.goto(this.url);

        // accept cookies
        await page.evaluate(_ => {
            CookieInformation.submitAllCategories();
        });

        var productsRead = 0;
        var productsTotal = Number.MAX_VALUE;

        while (productsRead < 100) {
            // Wait for the required DOM to be rendered
            await page.waitForSelector('button.btn.btn-dark.border-radius.my-3');
            // Click button to read more products
            await page.evaluate(_ => {
                document.querySelector("button.btn.btn-dark.border-radius.my-3").click()
            });
            // Wait for it to load the new products
            await page.waitForSelector('div.col-10.col-sm-4.col-lg-2.text-center.mt-4.text-secondary');
            // Get number of products read and total
            const loadProducts = await page.evaluate(_ => {
                let p = document.querySelector("div.col-10.col-sm-4.col-lg-2").innerText.replace("INDLÆS FLERE", "").replace("Du har set ","").replace(" ", "").replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"").split("af ");
                return p;
            });

            console.log("Products (read/total): " + loadProducts);
            productsRead = loadProducts[0];
            productsTotal = loadProducts[1];

            // Now waiting for a div element
            await page.waitForSelector('div[data-productid]');

            const getProducts = await page.evaluate(_ => {
                return document.querySelectorAll('div');
            });

            // PROBLEM HERE!
            // Cannot convert undefined or null to object
            console.log("LENGTH: " + Array.from(getProducts).length);
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The callback passed to `page.evaluate` runs in the *emulated page* context, **not** in the standard scope of the Node script. Expressions can't be passed between the page and the Node script without careful considerations: most importantly, if something isn't serializable (converted into plain JSON), it can't be transferred.

`querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList, and NodeLists only exist on the front-end, not the backend. Similarly, NodeLists contain HTMLElements, which also only exist on the front-end.

Put all the logic that requires using the data that exists only on the front-end inside the `.evaluate` callback, for example:

```
const numberOfDivs = await page.evaluate(_ => {
  return document.querySelectorAll('div').length;
});
```

or

```
const firstDivText = await page.evaluate(_ => {
  return document.querySelector('div').textContent;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. So I guess I have to iterate through the nodelist in the evaluate context and build an array of product objects with the information I need.